# 9 books and 3 friends

Tags: combinatorics

There are 6 books of type A and 3 books of type B

There are 3 friends each one of them either take two books of type A or a book of type B.

How many ways can they choose the books ?

My attempt :-

The number of ways =$(6C_2 \times 4C_2 \times 2C_2)+(3C_1 \times 2C_1 \times 1C_1 )$

Is this correct ?

Comment: No, for a number of reasons.  First, if the first friend takes two books of type $A$, there are only *four* remaining for the second friend to take, not five.  Next, you seem to have made the assumption that if the first friend takes books of type $A$ that all remaining friends must also, or if the first friend takes books of type $B$ that all remaining friends must also.  What about the first friend taking books of type $A$ and the second friend changing that and taking a book of type $B$ instead?

Comment: Draw a decision tree...

Comment: I mistyped some thing , would you give it another look now ? @JMoravitz

Comment: You addressed the first concern in my comment.  The second concern is still there

Comment: Also, it should be clarified, whether or not the books are all distinct or not., or if all books of type $A$ are otherwise identical.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt:
Denote $x^{2}$: two books of type A, $y$: one book of type B. We get the generating function
$G\left ( x,y \right )=\left (x^{2} +y \right )^{3}=x^{6}+\binom{3}{1}x^{4}y+\binom{3}{2}x^{2}y^{2}+\binom{3}{3}y^{3}$.
Number of ways they can choose the books:
a/if the books of each type are identical:
$1+3+3+1=\boxed{8}$ ways.
b/if the books are all distinct:
$\binom{6}{2}.\binom{4}{2}.\binom{2}{2}.\frac{3!}{3!}+\binom{6}{2}.\binom{4}{2}.\binom{3}{1}.\frac{3!}{2!}+\binom{6}{2}.\binom{3}{1}.\binom{2}{1}.\frac{3!}{2!}+\binom{3}{1}.\binom{2}{1}.\binom{1}{1}.\frac{3!}{3!}=90+810+270+6=\boxed{1176}$ ways.
(for example, $x^{6}$: two books of type A for each friend $\rightarrow \binom{6}{2}.\binom{4}{2}.\binom{2}{2}.\frac{3!}{3!}=90$ ways).